# Hide a keyboard return button

Tags: ios, swift3

I am have multiple TextFields in this ViewController in which for some textfields i need numeric keyboard with a return button and two textfields with alphanumeric keyboard and one textfield with a date picker.
  Everything is working fine but when I click on a textfield with alphanumeric keyboard, the return button from the numeric keyboard also appears.

The lastTransaction and remarks textfields have alphanumeric keyboards where I get return button

Please help me how do I remove that return button.

Below is the code.

```
import UIKit

class ATMDiscrepancyViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate
{
var datePicker : UIDatePicker!

@IBOutlet weak var Shortage50: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var shortage100: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var shortage500: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var shortage2000: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var overage50: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var overage100: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var overage500: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var overage2000: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var soild50: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var soild100: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var soild2000: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var newbd50: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var newbd100: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var newbd500: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var newbd2000: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var closingbd50: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var closingbd2000: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var oldbd50: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var oldbd100: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var oldbd500: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var wrongfeed500: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var wrongfeed50: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var wrongfeed2000: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var preclosing50: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var preclosing500: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var preclosing2000: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var remarks: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var lastTransaction: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var eodDateTime: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var preclosing100: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var wrongfeed100: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var oldbd2000: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var closingbd500: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var closingbd100: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var soild500: UITextField!
var atmData : SelectedATM! 
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
var activeField: UITextField?
var ATMTransBefore : ATMTransactionEODS1Model? = nil
var ATMTransAfter : ATMTransactionEODS1Model? = nil
var ATMCounterBefore : ATMCounterModel? = nil
var ATMCounterAfter : ATMCounterModel? = nil
var ATMPhysical : PhysicalModel? = nil
var ATMMAster : ATMMasterModel? = nil
var selectedDate : String = ""
var alertControllerScanCode:CustViewController!
let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.custom)

@IBOutlet weak var saveAction: UIButton!

func datePickerValuechanged (sender : UIDatePicker)
{
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.medium
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.none
    eodDateTime.text = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
    selectedDate = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
    self.view.endEditing(true)

}

@IBAction func eodAction(_ sender: UITextField) {
    deregisterFromKeyboardNotifications()
    self.button.isHidden=true
    self.pickUpDate(eodDateTime)
}
func pickUpDate(_ textField : UITextField){
    deregisterFromKeyboardNotifications()
    self.button.isHidden=true
    self.button.isEnabled = false
     NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ATMDiscrepancyViewController.keyboardRemoveReturn(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    // DatePicker
    self.datePicker = UIDatePicker(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 216))
    self.datePicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    self.datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.dateAndTime
    textField.inputView = self.datePicker

    // ToolBar
    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.barStyle = .default
    toolBar.isTranslucent = true
    toolBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 92/255, green: 216/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1)
    toolBar.sizeToFit()

    // Adding Button ToolBar
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(ATMDiscrepancyViewController.doneClick))
    let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(ATMDiscrepancyViewController.cancelClick))
    toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
    toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    textField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar

}


func doneClick() {
    let dateFormatter1 = DateFormatter()
   // let timeFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter1.dateStyle = .medium
    dateFormatter1.timeStyle = .none
    dateFormatter1.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS"
    eodDateTime.text = dateFormatter1.string(from: datePicker.date)

    eodDateTime.resignFirstResponder()
}
func cancelClick() {
    eodDateTime.resignFirstResponder()
}

func handleDatePicker(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    eodDateTime.text = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
    selectedDate = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)  
}

func doneButton(sender:UIButton)
{
    eodDateTime.resignFirstResponder() // To resign the inputView on clicking done.
    eodDateTime.text = selectedDate

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.title = "Discrepancy"

    registerForKeyboardNotifications()

    button.setTitle("Return", for: UIControlState())
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: UIControlState())
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 163, width: 106, height: 53)
    button.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ATMDiscrepancyViewController.Done(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)


    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ATMDiscrepancyViewController.dismissKeyboard))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    self.Shortage50.delegate = self
    self.shortage100.delegate = self
    self.shortage500.delegate = self
    self.shortage2000.delegate = self
    self.overage50.delegate = self
    self.overage100.delegate = self
    self.overage500.delegate = self
    self.overage2000.delegate = self
    self.soild50.delegate = self
    self.soild100.delegate = self
    self.soild500.delegate = self
    self.soild2000.delegate = self
    self.newbd50.delegate = self
    self.newbd100.delegate = self
    self.newbd500.delegate = self
    self.newbd2000.delegate = self
    self.closingbd50.delegate = self
    self.closingbd100.delegate = self
    self.closingbd500.delegate = self
    self.closingbd2000.delegate = self
    self.oldbd50.delegate = self
    self.oldbd100.delegate = self
    self.oldbd500.delegate = self
    self.oldbd2000.delegate = self
    self.wrongfeed50.delegate = self
    self.wrongfeed100.delegate = self
    self.wrongfeed500.delegate = self
    self.wrongfeed2000.delegate = self
    self.preclosing50.delegate = self
    self.preclosing100.delegate = self
    self.preclosing500.delegate = self
    self.preclosing2000.delegate = self
    self.remarks.delegate = self
    self.lastTransaction.delegate = self
    self.eodDateTime.delegate = self

}


override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}


func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if textField == self.lastTransaction || textField == self.remarks {

         let textString = (textField.text as! NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)

         return true
    }
    let allowedCharacters = CharacterSet.decimalDigits
    let characterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: string)
    return allowedCharacters.isSuperset(of: characterSet)

}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    self.Shortage50.resignFirstResponder()
    self.shortage100.resignFirstResponder()
    self.shortage500.resignFirstResponder()
    self.shortage2000.resignFirstResponder()

    self.overage50.resignFirstResponder()
    self.overage100.resignFirstResponder()
    self.overage500.resignFirstResponder()
    self.overage2000.resignFirstResponder()

    self.soild50.resignFirstResponder()
    self.soild100.resignFirstResponder()
    self.soild500.resignFirstResponder()
    self.soild2000.resignFirstResponder()

    self.Shortage50.becomeFirstResponder()
    self.lastTransaction.resignFirstResponder()
    self.remarks.resignFirstResponder()

    if textField == self.Shortage50
    {
        if isEmptyValidate(edit: self.Shortage50) == true
        {
            return false
        }
        self.shortage100.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    if textField == self.shortage100
    {
        if isEmptyValidate(edit: self.shortage100) == true
        {
            return false
        }
        self.shortage500.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    if textField == self.shortage500
    {
        if isEmptyValidate(edit: self.shortage500) == true
        {
            return false
        }
        self.shortage2000.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    if textField == self.shortage2000
    {
        if isEmptyValidate(edit: self.shortage2000) == true
        {
            return false
        }
        self.overage50.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    if textField == self.overage50
    {
        if isEmptyValidate(edit: self.overage50) == true
        {
            return false
        }
        self.overage100.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    if textField == self.overage100
    {
        if isEmptyValidate(edit: self.overage100) == true
        {
            return false
        }
        self.overage500.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    if textField == self.overage500
    {
        if isEmptyValidate(edit: self.overage500) == true
        {
            return false
        }
        self.overage2000.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    if textField == self.overage2000
    {
        if isEmptyValidate(edit: self.overage2000) == true
        {
            return false
        }
        self.soild50.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    if textField == self.soild50
    {
        if isEmptyValidate(edit: self.soild50) == true
        {
            return false
        }
        self.soild100.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    if textField == self.soild100
    {
        if isEmptyValidate(edit: self.soild100) == true
        {
            return false
        }
        self.soild500.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    if textField == self.soild500
    {
        if isEmptyValidate(edit: self.soild500) == true
        {
            return false
        }
        self.soild2000.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    if textField == self.soild2000
    {
        if isEmptyValidate(edit: self.soild2000) == true
        {
            return false
        }

        self.button.isHidden=true
         self.lastTransaction.becomeFirstResponder()
        dismissKeyboard()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillBeHidden(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)

    }
    if textField == self.lastTransaction
    {
        if isEmptyValidate(edit: self.lastTransaction) == true
        {
            return false
        }
        self.button.isHidden = true
        self.remarks.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    if textField == self.remarks
    {
        if isEmptyValidate(edit: self.remarks)
        {
            return false
        }

    }

    return true

  }

  func valid() -> Bool
  {
      if isEmptyValidate(edit: Shortage50) == true
    {
        return false
    }
    if isEmptyValidate(edit: shortage100) == true
    {
        return false
    }
    if isEmptyValidate(edit: shortage500) == true
    {
        return false
    }
    if isEmptyValidate(edit: shortage2000) == true
    {
        return false
    }
    if isEmptyValidate(edit: overage50) == true
    {
        return false
    }
    if isEmptyValidate(edit: overage100) == true
    {
        return false
    }
    if isEmptyValidate(edit: overage500) == true
    {
        return false
    }
    if isEmptyValidate(edit: overage2000) == true
    {
        return false
    }
    if isEmptyValidate(edit: soild50) == true
    {
        return false
    }
    if isEmptyValidate(edit: soild100) == true
    {
        return false
    }
    if isEmptyValidate(edit: soild500) == true
    {
        return false
    }
    if isEmptyValidate(edit: soild2000) == true
    {
        return false
    }
    if isEmptyValidate(edit: eodDateTime) == true
    {
        return false
    }
    return true
}

func isEmptyValidate(edit : UITextField) ->Bool
{
    if edit.text?.isEmpty ?? true
    {
        edit.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Enter value", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.red])
        return true
    }
    return false
}


func registerForKeyboardNotifications(){


    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillBeHidden(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)

}


func deregisterFromKeyboardNotifications(){
    //Removing notifies on keyboard appearing
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification){
    //Need to calculate keyboard exact size due to Apple suggestions
    self.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
    var info = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.size
    let contentInsets : UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardSize!.height, 0.0)

    self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

    var aRect : CGRect = self.view.frame
    aRect.size.height -= keyboardSize!.height
    if let activeField = self.activeField{
        if (!aRect.contains(activeField.frame.origin)){
            self.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(activeField.frame, animated: true)
        }
    }
}

func keyboardWillBeHidden(notification: NSNotification){
    //Once keyboard disappears, restore original positions
    var info = notification.userInfo!
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    self.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField){
    activeField = textField

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ATMDiscrepancyViewController.keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)


}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField){
    activeField = nil
}
func dismissKeyboard() {
    view.endEditing(true)
}




func keyboardWillShow(_ note : Notification) -> Void{
    DispatchQueue.main.async { () -> Void in
        self.button.isHidden = false
        self.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
        var info = note.userInfo!
        let keyBoardWindow = UIApplication.shared.windows.last
        self.button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: (keyBoardWindow?.frame.size.height)!-53, width: 106, height: 53)
        keyBoardWindow?.addSubview(self.button)
        keyBoardWindow?.bringSubview(toFront: self.button)
        let keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.size
        let contentInsets : UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardSize!.height, 0.0)

        self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
        self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

        var aRect : CGRect = self.view.frame
        aRect.size.height -= keyboardSize!.height
        if let activeField = self.activeField {
            if (!aRect.contains(activeField.frame.origin)){
                self.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(activeField.frame, animated: true)
            }
        }


        UIView.animate(withDuration: (((note.userInfo! as NSDictionary).object(forKey: UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey) as AnyObject).doubleValue)!, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.view.frame = self.view.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: 0)
        }, completion: { (complete) -> Void in

        })



    }

}

func Done(_ sender : UIButton){

    DispatchQueue.main.async { () -> Void in

        self.textFieldShouldReturn(self.activeField!)
    }

}


func keyboardRemoveReturn(_ note : Notification) -> Void{
    DispatchQueue.main.async { () -> Void in
        self.button.isHidden = true

        UIView.animate(withDuration: (((note.userInfo! as NSDictionary).object(forKey: UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey) as AnyObject).doubleValue)!, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.view.frame = self.view.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: 0)
        }, completion: { (complete) -> Void in

        })
    }

}
```

Thanks..

Comment: try lastTransaction.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = false to disable return key

Comment: @suhit i have used a custom button for return.. so this does not work

Comment: Why can't you use IQKeyboardManager, you will not need to add custom buttons on textfield. 

https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

Comment: can anybody help me out with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that text filed delegate is set.

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

   if textField == self.lastTransaction || textField == remarks {
    self.button.isHidden = true; //button is Return button
   } else {
    //show as you required 
   }
   return true
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works but only for lastTransaction textfield and not for remarks and eoddatetime textfields

Comment: Just put debug point in `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` and check when remark textfield is tapped then check self.button.isHidden property.

Answer (score 0):

try this!

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
if textField == self.lastTransaction  {
    self.button.isHidden = true;
}
 }
```

Comment: Thanks I tried this now but This also does not work.

Answer (score 0):

you can assign the tag to the cancelButton of UIToolbar

```
let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(VC.cancelClick))
cancelButton.tag = 1001
```

then implement the [UITextFieldDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate) method `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` where you can check the textField type and disable the cancel/return button

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
     if textField == self.lastTransaction {
        let cancelButton = toolBar.subviews.flatMap ({ $0 as? UIBarButtonItem }).filter { $0.tag == 1001 }.first as! UIBarButtonItem
        cancelButton.isEnabled = false
     }
     return true
}
```

Comment: have you added the tag to cancelButton? try adding breakpoint and check